# How do I handle this FileNotFoundException?

Tags: java, exception, filenotfoundexception

```
    File file=new File("login.properties");
    FileInputStream input=null;
    try{
         input=new FileInputStream(file);// line33
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Properties prop =new Properties();
    prop.load(input);
    input.close();
```

> I'm getting FileNotFoundException at line33. i have "login.properties" file in WebContent folder.
>   Where do I exactly place that file?

Comment: where is your class exist ?

Comment: For given relative path of login.properties, its necessary that it should reside in the same directory where your java file resides.

Comment: System.out.println(new File("login.properties").getAbsolutePath());

you'll get a directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will take it as you are trying to make a webapp.

You can access a path using `request.getRealPath(request.getServletPath());` after that you can add the rest of the path of your file.

For example in weblogic you will get your path till your domain `c:\oracle\middleware\oracle_home\user_projects\domains\YourDomain\` returned by above code.

your file might reside in `applications\YourApplication\WEB-INF\login.properties` inside `YourDomain` folder.
So use above code to get path till your domain, then add rest of the path yourself.

The best way is to put the path in `web.xml` using `context-param`

```
<context-param>
<param-name>loginPropFileLoc</param-name>
<param-value>c:\oracle\middleware\oracle_home\user_projects\domains\YourDomain\YourApplication\WEB-INF\login.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Then access the login properties file.Through this value.

ELSE put the properties file in the same directory where your class file is present.
If your class file is in `\abcd\ReadProperty.class` then put property file as `\abcd\login.properties`